# What's the measure of the radius of the circle below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the figure, calculate $R$. If : $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{AB}= 120°$, $CM = 1$ and $MB = 2$

(Answer: $\frac{3}{4}(\sqrt{3}+1$))

My progress:
[image]

Draw OP

Th.Chords:

$CM.MP = BM.AM \implies 1.[(R-1)+(R)] = 2.AM\\
\boxed{2AM = 2R-1}: \boxed{R=AM+ \frac{1}{2}}\\
\triangle AOB (isósceles):$\
Draw $AE$
$\implies$
$\triangle EAB(right): 
AE^2+(2+AM)^2 = 4R^2\\
AE^2 +4+4AM + AM^2 = 4R^2\\
AE^2 + 4+8R-4 + R^2 - R+\frac{1}{4} = 4R^2\\
4AE^2+16+32R - 16+4R^2-4R+1 = 16R^2\\
4AE^2+28R-12R^2+1 = 0 \implies\\
AE^2 = 12R^2-28R-1\\$

...?
I have not found another relationship with AM

Comment: $AM = r - 1/2, AB = r + 3/2$. $ \frac{\sqrt3}{2} r = \frac{AB}{2} = r/2 + 3/4$. Solve for $r$

Comment: @MathLover Thanks for help.....I fInd another solution..

Comment: Yes I saw. By the way, in addition to euclidean and plane geometry, you should also use _geometry_ tag in your questions.

Comment: @MathLover 
I will start adding this tag to the next questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\angle AOB = 120^o$

Law of cosines:

$AB^2 = 2R^2 + 2R^2 \cdot \frac 12 = 3R^2 \implies AB = R \sqrt3$

Power point M:
$1 \cdot (2R-1) = 2 \cdot (R \sqrt3 - 2) \iff 2R -1 = 2R\sqrt3 - 4 \iff R = \frac3{2(\sqrt3-1)} = \frac{3(\sqrt3+1)}4$

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite follow your work, but you should be able to get a relation with $AM$ and $R$ by using the fact that $OAB$ is a 30-30-120 triangle.

Hint for one possible alternate method:  Drop an altitude from $ON$ to $AB$.  So $N$ is the midpoint of $AB$.  Now focus on the lengths $OM,MN,NB,BO,ON$, writing what you can in terms of the radius $R$.

Let me know if I should elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Extend $\overline{CMO}$ to meet the circle at E and Extend $\overline{AO}$ to meet the circle at $D$. As $\triangle ABD$ is a 30-60-90 triangle $AB=R\sqrt{3}$. Since $BM=2$ and $AM=R\sqrt{3}-2$.

Now, look at $\triangle ACM$ and $\triangle BEM$ they are similar.

$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{R\sqrt{3}-2}{2R-1}$

After solving for R you get,

$R=\frac{3}{2(\sqrt{3}-1)}$

by getting the decimal value for R,

$R=2.04$

The decimal value of the answer you have posted is also 2.04

Then the proof will be true

Comment: you are welcome